# When using forEach in a Cloud Function, I can't make .sendToDevice() method work

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can send messages to the iOS device using the second function shown below.
I get the document id in the collection name "users" which is at the first level and send the message using the token stored in the tokens subcollection therefore `admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId).collection('tokens')`.

I have to change the way the function looks for the user. Rather than relying on the document id of the user, I now need a query in order to find the user. Being a query, unless I'm wrong, I'm forced to use forEach in order to send the message to the user. The function now looks as shown immediately below. In essence, once I know I have the user that needs to receive the message, I'm using the original function format to send the message but the message is never sent. All I see in the logs is Firebase messaging error and I have yet to figure out where the mistake is.

```
exports.sendMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (res, response) => {

const body = res.body;
const orderTotal = body.total;
const orderId = String(body.id);

const query = await usersRef.where('token', '==', token).get();

if (query.empty) {
    console.log('No matching documents.');
    return;
}

query.forEach(doc => {

    const tokens = usersRef.doc(doc.id).collection('tokens');
    tokens.get()

        .then(snapshot => {

            const results = [];

            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                const fcmToken = doc.data().fcmToken
                console.log("fcmToken =>", fcmToken);
                results.push(fcmToken);
            })

            const payload = {
                notification: {
                    title_loc_key: 'notify_title',
                    subtitle_loc_key: 'notify_subtitle',
                    body_loc_key: 'notify_body',
                    badge: '1',
                    sound: 'cha-ching.caf',
                    mutable_content: 'true'
                },
                data: {
                    'total': orderTotal,
                    'orderId': orderId
                }
            }
        
            response.send([results, , payload])
        
            admin.messaging().sendToDevice(results, payload).then((response) => {
                // Response is a message ID string.
                console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
                return { success: true };
            }).catch((error) => {
                return { error: error.code };
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("Error getting documents", err);
        });


});

});
```

This is the original function which I used when using the document id.

```
exports.sendMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (res, response) => {

const body = res.body
const orderTotal = body.total
const orderId = String(body.id)

const tokenReference = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId).collection('tokens')
const tokenSnapshots = await tokenReference.get()

const results = []

tokenSnapshots.forEach(tokenSnapshot => {
    const fcmToken = tokenSnapshot.data().fcmToken
    results.push(fcmToken)
})

const payload = {
    notification: {
        title_loc_key: 'notify_title',
        subtitle_loc_key: 'notify_subtitle',
        body_loc_key: 'notify_body',
        badge: '1',
        sound: 'cha-ching.caf',
        mutable_content: 'true'
    },
    data: {
        'total': orderTotal,
        'orderId': orderId
    }
}

response.send([results, , payload])

admin.messaging().sendToDevice(results, payload).then((response) => {
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
    return { success: true };
}).catch((error) => {
    return { error: error.code };
})

})
```

Screenshot of the error:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `onRequest()` function terminates when you return a response. You are using `sendToDevice()` after `response.send()`. Also make sure you are handling all the promises correctly. Try refactoring the using `async-await` syntax as shown below:

```
exports.sendMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (res, response) => {
  try {
    const body = res.body;
    const orderTotal = body.total;
    const orderId = String(body.id);

    const query = await usersRef.where("token", "==", "TOKEN").get();

    if (query.empty) {
      console.log("No matching documents.");
      return;
    }

    // Query tokens of all users at once
    const tokenSnapshots = await Promise.all(
      query.docs.map((user) => usersRef.doc(user.id).collection("tokens").get())
    );

    // Array of all fcmTokens
    const results = tokenSnapshots.reduce((acc, snapshot) => {
      acc = [...acc, ...snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data().fcmToken)];
      return acc;
    }, []);

    const payload = { ...FCM_PAYLOAD };

    const fcmResponse = await getMessaging().sendToDevice(results, payload);

    console.log("Successfully sent message:", fcmResponse);

    response.send([results, , payload]);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    response.json({ error: "An error occured" });
  }
});
```

Also checkout [Terminating HTTP Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#terminating_http_functions).

Comment: I'm still getting this error: results: [ { error: [FirebaseMessagingError] } ]. Really like your 'query' and 'results'. Any suggestions on tutorials for Cloud Functions?

Comment: @GIJoeCodes there must be some more details about the error? Can you share a screenshot of the logs perhaps? You can checkout [this series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM) to learn more about Cloud Functions.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the error from the Functions > Logs. Disregard the long id eoJy... That is just console log of results. newOrderCreated is the name of the function as opposed to the name shown above 'sendMessage'. Last, I replaced getMessaging() with admin.messaging(). I was getting an error of getMessaging not being recognized.

Comment: @GIJoeCodes yes `getMessaging()` is introduced in V10 of Admin SDK. Are the notifications being sent?

Comment: Notifications are not being sent. I get the error  getMessaging is not defined. I'm using v 11.1.0. I'm looking at the documentation and some other posts here in stackoverflow. It seems others have had this issue as well. I also tried getMessaging().send() and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After days of working on this, it turns out there wasn't anything wrong with the function. I don't know how **VPN** works but the fact that I had it enabled on my iPhone was the reason I wasn't getting the notification.

I paused the **VPN** and the notification was received.